# Need to make my jquery site scrolling (swiping) on iphone?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, scroll, swipe

I have one big problem, I have site that I've made that works on desktop computers but not on a mobiles (touchscreens) and iPhone & iPad. In the site I have scrolling on mouse wheel in directions up/down, and with key buttons in all four directions (left/right/up/down), how do I make swipe commands work here also?

I have site that is like http://socketstudios.com/!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at JQuery Mobile event that are build for this kind of feature.

For example: 
http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/

Comment: Hello Djavier89! I tried that but that doesn't work for me. I have a site similar to http://socketstudios.com/ and I want it to scroll in all directions in touchscreens like desktops... :/ Thank you

Comment: Voyager, what about having the **swipe** event to fires up the same method/event you trigger when pressing the arrow keys or scrolling up and down with the mouse. Based on the information you have provided its difficult to give you a good answere since it would depends upon the site design/structure

Comment: I tried that but id doesn't work. Script use this code to fire up events on key press:  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       scroll_left();
       return false;
    }
  });
  
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       scroll_up();
       return false;
    }
  });
  
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       scroll_right();
       return false;
    }
  });
  
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       scroll_down();
       return false;
    }
  });

Comment: I've uploaded my site and whole script package, you can see al js and jquerry files. I can't find where to insert which line of code... Thank you very much in advance. Here is a link http://www.mediafire.com/?a2yltriyzur5ac3 you can download and test it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to bind swipe events: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/

Example: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/Basic_swipe.html
Example code:

```
$("#test").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
       alert("Swiped 50px left")
    },
    threshold:50
  });
```

The code above does not move your page directly! There for you can use the property `swipeStatus`

```
$("#test4").swipe( { swipeStatus:swipe2, allowPageScroll:"vertical"} );
```

Try this:

```
$("body").swipe( {
 swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
       scroll_up();
    },
    swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
       scroll_down();
    },
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
       scroll_left();
    },
    swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
       scroll_right();
    }
});
```

Comment: As I said I have site that is similar like http://socketstudios.com/ and I need basic instructions like where to put which line of code and where to edit code exactly as I am new to jQuerry and touch plugin. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've uploaded my site and whole script package, you can see al js and jquerry files. I can't find where to insert which line of code... Thank you very much in advance. Here is a link mediafire.com/?a2yltriyzur5ac3 you can download and test it

Comment: I can see you already fixed your issue? So I don't need to download the files?

Comment: No Niels, it doesn't work on iPad or iPhones. Scrolling works only or desktops... Tnx in advance